# ERROR: Loading of original wasm failed

Tags: ink, rust, wasm, cargo, cargo-contract

I having some trouble running the Flipper example from the Ink! webpage.

The `cargo contract build` outputs the following error log:

```
ERROR: Loading of original wasm failed

Caused by:
    0: Loading of wasm module at '/Users/winston/workspace/cs/repos/flipper/target/ink/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/flipper.wasm' failed
    1: Unknown opcode 192
```

rustup show output:

```
Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/winston/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

aarch64-apple-darwin
wasm32-unknown-unknown
wasm32-wasi

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.70.0-nightly (17c116721 2023-03-29)
```

As you can see, I am running on the M1 OSX system.

Comment: Please, remember to mark this question as solved :)

Comment: Rustc v1.70.0 dont work either so consider sticking with 1.68.0 or 1.69.0 stable

Comment: I'm running into this in 1.71.1 - what might be the reason?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved! This was caused by the nightly toolchain. Switching to the stable toolchain solved this issue.

Edit: As pointed out by Shunsuke, this is specific to the 1.70.0 nightly build. 1.68.0 version seems to work.

Edit (12th June 2023): If you are using the latest version 3.0.1 of `cargo-contract --version` then you must fallback to 1.69 (since neither stable or nightly 1.70.0 worked). The CI for cargo-contract has pinned that version, see https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/blob/master/.github/workflows/ci.yml#LL184C62-L184C118

```bash
rustup update stable
rustup install 1.69
rustup default 1.69
rustup component add rust-src --toolchain 1.69
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain 1.69
cargo contract build
```

Comment: Lots of contracts including OpenBrush PSP22, PSP34 contracts using nightly features such as `#![feature(min_specialization)]`.

This means existing contracts cannot be compiled with nightly toolchain whose rustc version is higher than `1.70.0` (Confirmed `1.68.0` works).

cargo contract is now independent from nightly toolchain but it should still support nightly for compatibility.

Comment: https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/issues/1058

Comment: I just had this issue both using 1.70.0 stable & nightly. Fixed by changing back to 1.69 by running `rustup update && rustup install 1.69 && rustup default 1.69 && rustup override set 1.69 && rustup component add rust-src --toolchain 1.69 && cargo contract build`. Note that cargo-contract has pinned their CI to 1.69 https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/blob/master/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L185 due to this issue https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/issues/1139.

Comment: I was tired to try everything, but this works, even at the end I got this issue `info: installing component 'rust-std' for 'wasm32-unknown-unknown'
 18.2 MiB /  18.2 MiB (100 %)  17.3 MiB/s in  1s ETA:  0s
ERROR: Cannot infer the root project id`. Also I aded the rust-toolchain with `nightly-2023-02-07"` and cargo-contract version `cargo-contract v2.2.1`
`

Answer (score 4):

For cases where updated nightly is still preferred for whatever reason:

```
rustup update
```

```
rustup install nightly-2023-02-07-aarch64-apple-darwin
```

```
rustup component add rust-src --toolchain nightly-2023-02-07-aarch64-apple-darwin
```

...specify nightly version in tag

```
cargo +nightly-2023-02-07 contract build
```

Still running updated nightly rustc 1.70.0 as default:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding a rust toolchain override file can also work.

Such as this:

```
[toolchain]
channel = "nightly-2023-01-01"
components = [ "rustfmt" ]
targets = [ "wasm32-unknown-unknown" ]
profile = "minimal"
```

Answer (score 1):

ran into the same issue using v3.0 cargo contract ,
updating cargo contract to v4 solved it. Use

`cargo install --git https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract cargo-contract --force`

to update

Comment: you can also leave your rustc version as is... no need to downgrade