# Unable to deploy the open-brush contracts build using toolchain nightly-2023-02-07 on substrate node

Tags: ink, rust, smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node, openbrush

As you can see in following link . I was not able to build contract using latest rust nighly ( rustc 1.70.0-nightly (17c116721 2023-03-29))  toolchain.

[ERROR: Loading of original wasm failed](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7881/error-loading-of-original-wasm-failed)

I got the solution from git issues, here -
https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/issues/1058

But now when i am trying to deploy the contract on substrate node it is not responding.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you try to do, what you see, what was expected to happen and what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly downgrade your nightly version. There is some issue in the new update of the nightly.

Answer (score 0):

this is the output of 'rustup show' in my ubuntu machine.
(1.69.0-nigthtly is the maximum for the time being.)
[image]

I would advise for you to use [rustup override](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html#directory-overrides).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use `1.69` or lower with the current cargo contract v3. Will be addressed in v4 as far as I know

```sh
rustup default 1.69.0
```