# using String in ink version 4

Tags: ink, migration, cargo-contract, string

so I am migrating my contract from version 3 to 4
my goal is to use the open brush as well but we can not use the open brush in ink version 4 because it still needs the nightly features and Ink v4 runs on stable.

this is my current manifest file
[image]

now this works fine as long as I am building on nightly
`cargo +nightly contract build --release`

but I have a function that needs to convert a FixesI128 [from `fixed` crate]  to string which is where the issue is

[image]

everything is fine in this function except the highlighted line
so with this line, if I build a contract [on nightly] I get this error

[image]

but if I remove this line this compiles down successfully

also, one more thing I am using String from Openbrush and to string from ink prelude as you can see in the picture

[image]

please let me know if there is any solution

Comment: https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/issues/1058#issuecomment-1501225760

Comment: you can fix this issue using above link @Rahul navgire

Comment: i've got two comments to share. firstly you might be able to resolve that `ERROR: Loading of original wasm failed ... Unknown opcode 192` shown in your screenshot by following the steps i mentioned in this other issue https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7881/error-loading-of-original-wasm-failed/7882#7882 (i.e. use rust 1.69, not 1.70). secondly, if the value of `b` is `0`, then your line `let res = a / b` might result in overflow error. so i suggest seeing if you can use `checked_div`, and also make your return value a `Result<()>`, so you return `Ok` or `Err`.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: this is not completely correct answer anymore. Openbrush is using String type from ink! prelude since version 3.0.0

```
pub type String = ink::prelude::string::String;
```

---

When you look at the definition of `openbrush::traits::String` you can see that OB String is actually a vector `Vec<u8>`

```rust
pub struct String {
    vec: Vec<u8>,
}
```

One way to have both types of strings used is to use aliases:

```rust
use ink::prelude::string::{String as PreludeString};
use openbrush::traits::String;
```

Depending on your needs you can use either of them or both. I find using `from` to be more convenient  than `to_string()`

```rust
// ink::prelude's String
let s = PreludeString::from(res_str)

// OB version 
let s = String::from(res_str)
```